# XML RPC GUI for developers in Windows?

Tags: windows, xml, rpc

Is there something like [this](http://ditchnet.org/xmlrpc/) for Windows?

If not, what is the easiest/quickest way to test an XML RPC?

Comment: Nice tool. It would be pretty easy to do something like this in php but windows app... I'll look forward to see if someone know/make one :)

Comment: Yes, I might make one if it doesn't exist.  Would be a good excuse to make a Linux/Windows GUI app.

Comment: What client did you decide on?

Comment: @Znarkus I ended up making my own in Python.  If it were better, I'd release it, but it's very specific to my situation.

Comment: You can use Postman as XML RPC client. Set the Content-type: text/xml to header. At choose "raw" for body. Here's my blog post about Postman and XML RPC in Indonesian language. You got the idea https://mul14.wordpress.com/2016/03/22/postman-as-xml-rpc-client/

Answer (score 2):

I'm using xmlrpc-test-tool, a browser tool: http://code.google.com/p/xmlrpc-test/

Answer (score 0):

Browser tools:

Firefox: http://restclient.net/
Chrome: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm

Especially Postman for Chrome is just great!

Comment: These do not support XML-RPC, am I right?

Comment: @Kačer You can use Postman as XMP-RPC client. Just add "Content-Type: text/xml" to header, and choose "raw" for body. Type any XML you want. Here's the screenshot https://mul14.files.wordpress.com/2016/03/postman-as-xmlrpc-client.png