# how to validate odoo api in postman?

Tags: json, xml, api, odoo, postman

I want to generate a rest api in odoo so that it can be used in other languages. I have used below api's

1. http://URL_with_PORT/{}/xmlrpc/2/common
2. http://URL_with_PORT/{}/xmlrpc/2/object

but when I validated it using postman it is giving me error.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the curly braces in the URL. Just send it to the `xmlrpc/2/common` endpoint, as per...

```
http://<server:?port>/xmlrpc/2/common
```

You need to set the verb to `POST`, and the body to `raw` with `XML`.

Then send in the following XML in the form as per the documentation.

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<methodCall>
    <methodName>version</methodName>
</methodCall>
```

This will return the server version info as per the examples used in the External API [documentation](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/15.0/developer/misc/api/odoo.html) in an XML response.

Answer (score -3):

Postman isn't the best client to use XML-RPC calls, take a look at [XML RPC GUI for developers in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/683745/xml-rpc-gui-for-developers-in-windows). You have to create a raw request and then send it. Using SoapUI would be much easier.

Comment: Can you please give me the guideline to use SoapUI??
And one more thing forgot to mention that I am using Ubuntu system.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24535719/how-to-create-update-test-records-on-openerp-7-using-jmeter

Comment: take a look here https://www.surekhatech.com/blog/working-with-odoo-web-services?p_p_auth=01hlmsJ0

Comment: The question asks about POSTMAN, this answer is out of scope